# Showing that $ab=0$ implies $ba=0$ in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Question:
>
> Let $n$ be an integer greater than $1$. In a ring in which $x^{n}=x$ for all $x$, show that $ab=0$ implies $ba=0$.

$(ab)^{n}={ab\cdot\cdot\cdot ab}=a(ba\cdot\cdot\cdot ba)b$
there are $(n-1)$ factor of $b\cdot a$

$(ba)^{n-1}=b^{n-1}a^{n-1}=b^{n}b^{-1}\cdot a^{n}a^{-1}=bb^{-1}aa^{-1}$

I have looked at a number of solutions which begins with

> "note that $(ba)^{n}$"

which I dislike.

Is there an alternative solution that follows from my attempt?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem with your attempt is that $b^{-1}$ may not (should not even) exist.

Comment: What makes you say $(ba)^{n-1}=b^{n-1}a^{n-1}$? If there is commutativity then there is not much to prove. Then $ba=ab=0$. And why do you dislike $(ba)^n$?

Comment: You have to use the fact that $x^n=x$. The simplest non-trivial case of that is $x\cdot x=x$. How might you use that?

Comment: @drhab it isn't intuitive to me. Why is it necessary to begin the argument from $(ba)^{n}$

Comment: Then your intuition is "playing tricks with you". Having a good look at the argument beginning from $(ba)^n$ reveals that it is indeed very handsome to begin with $(ba)^n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$ba=(ba)^n=b(ab)a(ba)^{n-2}=b(0)a(ba)^{n-2}=0$

Comment: I'd put the $ba$ in front for clarity.

Comment: It is from $b(0)(ba)^{n-2}$, you have $b(0)=0, b(0)a=0a=0$ thus $b(0)a(ba)^{n-2}=0(ba)^{n-2}=0$

Comment: Sure, but the final $ba$ is a "surprise". Start with $ba = (ba)^n = \ldots$

Answer (score -2):

$0 = ab = (ab)^n = b(ab)^n a = (ba)(ba)^n = (ba)^n+1$ implies $ba = 0$. 
Using the result that in any ring with $x^n = x$ for all $x$ in the ring and if $a^m = 0$ for some $a$ in the ring then $a = 0$.